# Продолжить выполнение метода c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Можно ли каким то образом "сохранить состояние" к примеру метода при его выполнении, и после перезапуска программы продолжить выполнение с этой же строки? На самом деле я думал о том, что это можно сделать через огромное кол-во условий, но может есть более элегантный вариант?

Comment: Ну только если как-то предусмотреть выгрузку/загрузку состояния. Без деталей тут сложно. И нужно искать компромисс - возможно, стоит потерять часть проделанной работы, но уменьшить количество данных, которые нужны для инициализации.

Comment: Состояние метода нельзя. 
Но есть состояние у объектов, их можно сохранить в файл или БД, а потом прочитать в другом инстансе и продолжить выполнение

Answer (score 0):

Нет, такое не возможно.
Но решение естественно есть.

1. Создайте объект прогресса(класс, каркас или переменную базового типа).\
2. Каждую итерацию вашей операции сохраняйте в него прогресс и частичный результат. 
   Далее выбирайте один из вариантов:
3. 1 - Сохранять автоматически прогресс раз в какое-то время (Например, 10 секунд, через Thread while сохранять в файл), далее при загрузке программы автоматически загрузить прогресс (или дать пользователю кнопку для выбора файла) 
   2 - Сохранять/Загружать прогресс только через кнопку.

```
class Progress
{
   public Progress(int startIndex, int endIndex, int currentIndex, int sum)
   {
      StartIndex = startIndex;
      EndIndex = endIndex;
      CurrentIndex = currentIndex;
      Sum = sum;
   }
   public int StartIndex, EndIndex, CurrentIndex, Sum;
}
```

```
string path = @"C:\progress.txt";
void Load()
{
    progress = new Progress(/*Получение из файла прогресса*/);
}
void Save()
{
    //Сохранения прогресса, можно как отделить переменные пробелом, записать их побайтно или же в Json-формате
}
Progress progress;
void Start()
{
   for(; progress.CurrentIndex < progress.EndIndex; progress.CurrentIndex++)
   {
       progress.Sum += progress.CurrentIndex;
       Save();
   }
}
```

Если вы используете многопоточность не забывайте использовать lock.